# Evaluate discount promotion in Product Detail Page

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

**Scenario :**

- I've been trying to implement something like Amazon has on their product pages in, 
  **where the non promoted price is crossed, and the promoted price is highlighted.**
- I have the PROMOTIONS product option selected in the controller, and
  it is returning the potencialPromotion, but it doesn't have the value
  of the discount in that structure only the message (as on the
  Accelerator it appears the message).
- I'm in Hybris 6.6 and I looked up the **DefaultPromotionEngineService.evaluate** method because it is used in the Cart, and for the cart it returns the promotion actions, but the equivalent method for the product isn't returning anything.

Has anybody done this? 
Seems like a pretty convencional request although I know it goes against the flexibility of promotion engine.

I can use a Regex against the message to get the discount, but it's a road I don't want to take because it will end badly....

Please suggest.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned it before, I have answered based on Legacy Promotion, not the Promotion Engine. I'll update answer if there is a way to do the same in Promotion Engine.

---

It's true, OOTB there is no service which gives you the discount price on PDP.

I think what you can do,

Override **PromotionsPopulator** to get the discount value and set it to promotionData.

```
if (fixedPricePromotion instanceof ProductFixedPricePromotionModel) 
{
    PromotionPriceRowModel promotionPriceRowModel = ((ProductFixedPricePromotionModel)source).getProductFixedUnitPrice();
    //TODO: covert promotionPriceRowModel to promotionPriceData
    //TODO: set to promotionData
}
```

**ProductPromotionsPopulator** internally calls the above populator to convert ProductPromotionModel to data.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can achieve this using the price row. We can create one more price row and display the logic correctly based on the discount price.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be good if you could provide some example code, or even some psuedo code to explain how your suggestion would solve the OP's issue. Otherwise it's unclear how this would work.